# Csv to PDF PDFBOX?

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox

I'm new to java, and I'm learning how to create PDF, I was using Itext to create PDF, but because it handles a license I stopped using it, and started using PDFbox. I've searched the internet for how to convert from CSV to PDF, but I can't find an example of how to use margins, or how to align the content.

Using Itext, this is my code using Itext7, it works perfectly but i want to migrate it to PDFbox

```
   public static boolean isEmpty(File rutaCSV) {
        if(rutaCSV.isDirectory()){
            String[] csvFiles = rutaCSV.list();
            if (csvFiles.length > 0) {
                for (String cadena : csvFiles){
                    readCSV("path");
                    try{
                       File csvFile = new File("path");
                       if (csvFile.exists()){
                           csvFile.delete();
                           return false;
                           
                       }
                        System.out.println(csvFile.delete());
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }else{
                System.out.println("There's not files");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
     public static void readCSV(String file, String cadena){
        try{
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file);
            // Configuración para leer el archivo con ;

            CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(';').build();
            
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(filereader)
                                  .withCSVParser(parser)
                                  .build();
            
            Document pdfDocument = new Document();
            pdfDocument.addTitle("Some");
            pdfDocument.setMargins(0, 0,25,25);
            String fileName = cadena.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");
            PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, new FileOutputStream("path"+fileName+".pdf"));
            
            pdfDocument.open();
            
            PdfPTable tableData = new PdfPTable(5);
                        
            PdfPCell cells;
            
            // Lista para guardar los datos leídos
            List<String[]> allData = csvReader.readAll();
            for (String[] row : allData) {
                for (String cell : row) {
                    cells =new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell));
                    tableData.addCell(cells);
                }
            }
            pdfDocument.addTitle("Some");
            pdfDocument.add(tableData);                       
            pdfDocument.close(); 
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
```

Using PDFBox

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CsvException {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        document.addPage(page);
        PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        try{
            String file = "C:\\Users\\brayan.milian\\Desktop\\pruebaFTP\\prueba.csv";
            FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file);
            CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(';').build();

            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(filereader)
                                  .withCSVParser(parser)
                                  .build();
            List<String[]> allData = csvReader.readAll();    
            for (String row[] : allData) {
                for (String cell : row){
                    content.beginText();
                    content.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_BOLD, 12);
                    content.showText(cell);
                    content.endText(); 
                }
            }  
        content.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("dja");
        }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You likely need something on top of PDFBox, e.g. boxable or easytable.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks dude, I saw some examples and the implementation it's easy, for boxable

Comment: Please delete the question or answer it yourself.